# Microsoft fonts license on linux

Tags: fonts, ms-office

Is there any vendor who manages all fonts that comes with windows OS. My basic use-case is to get single license for all fonts available on windows system which I can legally use on linux servers. I don't want to manage fonts everytime on my own.

If you have any clue of managing MS fonts on linux environment please revert.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most of them have been designed in collaboration with Ascender (a Monotype subsidiary), which retained the right to sell them separately.

Thus, just shop for them on myfonts (another Monotype subsidiary), if you feel replacing the many nice free fonts available on Linux systems today is worth Monotype's pricing.